# This is the girl TO whom I married or whom I married

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-structure

I came across the both sentences:

> 1. This is the girl whom I married.
> 2. This is the girl **to** whom I married.

Which one is grammatical?
Please explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you use **to** depends on whether the verb requires a direct or indirect object.

For example, you would say:

> He is the man whom I saw at the market

The **man** is the direct object of the verb **saw** so you can't say **to whom I saw**.

But you can say:

> He is the man to whom I gave the letter.

Because what you gave was the letter, not the man. You gave the letter **to** the man. The man is the indirect object.

So the question is: does **marry** take a direct or indirect object. This gets a bit tricky because although **you marry someone**, you **get married to someone**.

In this instance, you have a choice. You can say either:

> This is the girl whom I married
>   or
>   This is the girl to whom I **am** married.